# Javascript functions as values and closure

Tags: javascript

I am grappling to understand functions as values, and closure in Javascript.

Consider the code;

```
function multiplier(factor) {
    return function (number) {return number * factor; }
}
var i = multiplier(10);
```

What is i actually holding at this point? I know I could use i next by doing something like

```
console.log(i(5));
```

which would produce the value 50. But I'd still like to know what Javascript actually gives to i before this.

Comment: `var i = function(number) { return number * 10; }`, this is what `multiplier` function returns.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if you find it sufficient, as per etiquette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following two examples. The first you have given and the second one I provided.

In the first one might think that the returned function is

```
function (number) {return number * 10; }
```

But this isn't really the case even if it is easy to think of it that way. `factor` is saved as a reference to the parameter `factor`. So the function `multiplier` returns a function with a reference to the value you provided.

If the value of `factor` changes then the function result is different.

```js
function multiplier(factor) {
    return function (number) {return number * factor; }
}
var i = multiplier(10);
console.log('Example1',i(5))

function multiplier2(factor) {
    setTimeout(() => {factor = 100}, 1000)
    return function (number) {return number * factor; }
}
var i2 = multiplier2(10);
console.log('Example2',i2(5))
setTimeout(() => {console.log('Example2',i2(5))}, 1100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = multiplier(10);
```

is actually `var i = function(number){return number * 10;}`

then when calling `console.log(i(5));`
you are calling

```
console.log(function(5){return 5* 10;})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So does Javascript give the variable i, a "frozen" function so to speak not an immutable value?

Comment: Yes you are right. Every single time you are calling the 'multiplier' function it be assigned as immutable value.

Comment: @Mamun This is not true. See my answer. Factor can be changed after the function is returned. The `factor´ only gets evaluated upon execution.

Comment: @E. Sundin Yes factor is specific only to the instance when created. You have make a call to the function second time in which case the instance will be the whole new one.

Answer (score -1):

`i` is actually a brand new function: `function (number) {return number * 10; }`

So if you have `j = multiplier(10);` actually `i` is not `j`, because they are 2 different functions

One more note is that, after `i = multiplier(10);` you no longer have `factor` as reference or as value anymore, `factor` already disappear from your `i`

Comment: Isn't the `10` actually `factor` which is saved as a reference from the scope from which it is created? If the factor parameter would change before the function is executed, then the answer from `multiplier(10)(5)` wont be 50.

Comment: after `i = multiplier(10);` you no longer have `factor` any more.

Comment: @Xin: That's untrue. You still have `factor` which is why the function works. Javascript function definition does not substitute variable values. Instead it references them. This "feature" is called a lexical closure (or just closure for short).

Comment: Thanks Xin, i understand the statements are invoking a new "instance" so to speak. What I'm interested in is how Javascript uses/evaluates function variables?